# How to get difference of columns in DataFrame Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diff, difference

I need to get a DataFrame with column difference of column that I choose (for example the last one)

I tried using `df.diff(axis=1, periods=1)` will count column difference with the next column. However, I want to get difference of columns with exactly one column (last one).

Comment: You want `df - df.iloc[:, -1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) for subtract by last column selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.sub(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0)
```

If need subtract by column selected by label:

```
df1 = df.sub(df['col'], axis=0)
```